# sharing variables across two aws lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda

I have two AWS lambda functions - lambdaA and lambdaB.

The http client calls API Gateway endpoint A that invokes lambdaA which generates a uuid and returns to the client.

The client then calls API Gateway endpoint B that invokes lambdaB and passes uuid generated by lambdaA to lambdaB. How does lambdaB verify the uuid is generated by lambdaA.

I could think of using a cache - elastic cache or db - dynamodb. But I don't like elastic cache as it runs a server and dynamodb is probably a little too heavy for my simple use case.

Is there any other simpler way of caching data with AWS lambda.

Comment: No there isn't a simpler way. ElastiCache or DynamoDB would be my recommendations.

Comment: DynamoDB is actually pretty lightweight for this type of thing.  However, if the two lambda functions are executed in parallel, it sounds like you may have race condition issues where function B is checking for data that has not yet been generated by function A.

Comment: Why not a S3 object? ElastiCache and DynamoDB seem overkill for what you are asking.

Comment: I think s3 would be too slow. Will try. I decided to use DynamoDB. There isn't an issue of race condition in my use case.

Comment: With DynamoDB you can use conditional writes to get around any race condition issues. Using S3 it would be more difficult to work around race conditions. S3 would also generally be slower since you would have to read the entire file contents each time, versus reading a single field value from DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB and Elasticache recommended.
Also, read the following article by Kenneth Falck:

[Amazon AWS Lambda data caching solutions compared](https://sc5.io/posts/amazon-aws-lambda-data-caching-solutions-compared/)

and [How HipChat Stores And Indexes Billions Of Messages Using ElasticSearch And Redis](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/1/6/how-hipchat-stores-and-indexes-billions-of-messages-using-el.html)